# Почему команда push не создает файлы на удаленном сервере?

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote, развертывание

Есть репозиторий на локальной машине и на удаленном сервере, `pull` и `push` выполняются без проблем и ошибок, собственно в чем проблема:

На локальной машине: создаю файл, коммит на его основе, заливаю на сервер:

```
touch test.html
git add test.html
git commit -m'added test.html'
git push
```

На сервере: коммит получен, файла нет.

```
git log
```

> (показывает, что последний коммит получен)

```
ls -A
```

> .git

Почему команда `git push` не создает файлы на удаленном сервере?

Comment: Что значит "только его нет на сервере" если "Смотрю git log на удаленном сервере, там все ок, коммит пришел с новым файлом"?

Comment: выложите лог терминала, `~/bash_history` или подобный

Comment: скорее всего на локальном компе другой бранч, чем на удаленном. Поэтому и не видите. [git branch](http://git-scm.com/book/ru/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) выведет список доступных бранчей и звездочкой обозначит текущий.

Answer (score 3):

Как правило, удаленный репозиторий является bare («голым»). Такой репозиторий используется только для хранения файлов Git и организации работы группы пользователей. Предполагается, что никто не будет создавать коммиты непосредственно на bare-репозитории. Это повышает надежность и экономит дисковое пространство.

Если вы хотите делать развертывание через Git, то это возможно через git-hooks: [Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью Git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428483/181472)

**Но это плохая практика.** (В том же вопросе объясняется, почему). Лучше использовать автоматизированные системы развертывания.

Answer (score 1):

У меня в очередной раз создаётся впечатление, что путаница между ftp и git слишком сильна. Поймите разницу между локальным репозиторием и удалённым: ["A remote repository is generally a bare repository — a Git repository that has no working directory."](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server).
Не стоит, да и не получится использовать удалённый репозиторий в качестве корневой папки вашего сайта. Нужно сделать там обычный репозиторий, и оттуда делать pull. Делать это автоматически помогут hook'и.

Comment: есть русский перевод упомянутой книги. в частности, вот [ссылка](http://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Git-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5) на ту же четвёртую главу.